# Cake PHP installation issues

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0, putty

I just started using Cake PHP. I installed through the "installatron" app.

I am accessing the command line through Putty as they recommend, which works fine. Changed `.htpaccess` as instructed, etc.

When ever I try to enter `bin/cake bake` it tells me

> Permission Denied

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

chmod 755 bin/cake fixed the issue